# Where to find required JRE files in OpenJDK for an JavaFX application to be wrapped using Launch4j

Tags: java, javafx, launch4j

I'm building a GUI application in Java using JavaFX. So far I've been using Oracle JDK but due to licensing issues, I've decided to move on to OpenJDK or Azul Zulu. They don't come with JavaFX so I [built OpenJFX](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX) myself on Ubuntu 16.04 ([running on WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)).

Now, to wrap the application using Launch4j, I need the only the required JRE files to keep the application size minimum. In Oracle JDK distributions JRE is simply found in [JRE folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930383/jre-installation-directory-in-windows), however, OpenJDK and OpenJFX have a different structure and I could not find (or missed, my bad) any documentation relevant to my question.

tl;dr: Need the location/path of minimum of required JRE files from OpenJDK and OpenJFX to wrap a cross-platform application using Lanuch4j.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes. I used jlink that's included in OpenJDK. A similar question had this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403071/create-jre-from-openjdk-windows).