# Error: This application requires a jre 1.6.0

Tags: java, windows

I have an application emSignerGSTN in my windows 10 machine. But while trying to run the application, I get the error:

```
This application requires a jre 1.6.0
```

I have openjdk installation of Azul Zulu :

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.40.0.25-CA-win64) (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.40.0.25-CA-win64) (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)

$ where java
C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8\bin\java.exe
```

The oracle java installation makes the application work. But I don't want to install it. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the problem. I have a JRE 1.8.0 installed in the machine. The problem is that the application doesn't look into that path. Java installation path is:

```
C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8\bin\java.exe
```

Copy the JRE folder of zulu jdk `C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8\jre` to emSigner installation path as `C:\Program Files (x86)\eMudhra Limited\emSigner\emSigner\jre`.

When running the application, emSigner will look for the JRE first in its installation path. Since it exists now, there is no need to look for an oracle JRE installation. Thus further errors are not shown.

Comment: if the `jre` folder doesn't exist in your openjdk installation, then follow these steps to create it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403071/create-jre-from-openjdk-windows